# Can you perform t-test to compare means if the data are a mixture of normal distributions?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test

I have two datasets and I wanted to compare if their means are the same, however datas follow a mixture of normal distributions with different means.When I plot datas they are both bimodal. Can I still do t-test on them and would the results be valid?

Comment: How large are the datasets?

Comment: I’d also consider if the mean is a very useful value to examine if you have multimodality. Maybe it is...but maybe not.

Comment: @whuber about 1000 rows for each data. (I compare 2 data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, almost all "normal" data are really a mixture of two or more normal distributions. For example, heights of students are often modeled as
normal. However, there is a known difference in
heights of several inches between men and women.
The difference is small, so the mixture distribution for men and women does not appear to be binomal.

For example, the 200 observations `x` might be a from a mixture of men and women in Country A and `y` might be a similar mixture for Country B.

```
set.seed(523)
x = c(rnorm(100, 65, 3), rnorm(100, 68, 3.5))
y = c(rnorm(100, 67, 3), rnorm(100, 70, 3.5))

par(mfrow = c(2,2));  mn=min(x,y); mx=max(x,y)
  hist(x, prob=T, xlim=c(mx,mn), col="skyblue2", main="A")
  qqnorm(x, main="Normal Probability Plot: A")
  hist(y, prob=T, xlim=c(mx,mn), col="skyblue2", main="B")
  qqnorm(y, main="Normal Probability Plot: B")
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

[image]

With 400 subjects from each country, the relatively small difference of about two inches between the two countries is detected. The sample means are significantly different at below the 1% level.

```
t.test(x,y)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -4.064, df = 397.78, p-value = 5.815e-05
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.2156924 -0.7709199
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 66.53548  68.02878
```

By contrast, we consider test scores in two different years for a population that is distinctly bimodal.
Here the two components within each group are more than two standard deviations apart so the histograms show bimodality.

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = c(rnorm(100, 50, 4), rnorm(100, 70, 4))
x2 = c(rnorm(100, 60, 3), rnorm(100, 80, 4))

par(mfrow = c(2,2));  mn=min(x1,x1); mx=max(x1,x2)
  hist(x1, prob=T, xlim=c(mx,mn), col="skyblue2", main="Year 1")
  qqnorm(x1, main="Normal Probability Plot: Yr. 1")
  hist(x2, prob=T, xlim=c(mx,mn), col="skyblue2", main="Year 2")
  qqnorm(x2, main="Normal Probability Plot: Yr. 2")
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

[image]

A Welch 2-sample t test detects the difference (of about 10 points) between the two years.

```
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -9.1307, df = 397.58, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -11.933062  -7.704791
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 59.98648  69.80541
```

Because the data are so obviously not normal, one may
doubt whether the P-value from the t test is accurate.
However, the issue is not so much whether the *data* are normal, but whether *means* of samples of size 200 are nearly
normally distributed.

The data in `x2` seem the most aggressively bimodal, so let's re-sample many $B = 100\,000$ groups of
200 with replacement from `x2`, the average $A$ for each re-sample is found, and see whether the $B$ sample means are
nearly normal. The histogram of re-sampled group averages seems to match reasonably well a normal curve with
$\mu = \bar A$ and $\sigma = S_A.$

```
set.seed(1234)
a = replicate(10^5, mean(sample(x2, 200, rep=T)))
hist(a, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, mean(a), sd(a)), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note:* In a comment @whuber asks how large a sample you have. I wouldn't want to use t tests for very small, distinctly bimodal datasets.

Consider the following dataset with $n=10$ observations:

[image]